# How to display success message after submission with Google Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I would like to add a submission success message, after the user has submitted the "form" on the Google web app. Indeed, there's currently a display error message that is displayed, as soon as not all fields are filled in. Instead, it clears out all fields after the form has been submtited. Shall I create a function `.return` in the HTML side ?

Please find below the code:

```
function doGet(e) {   
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('BS_webapp_fiche-compta'); 
}

function AddRecord(initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme) {   
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xPkCBdPAc0OOGTsDxSAz7Rx4kYEfqiEUsUCaYXFV-hc/edit#gid=1182006059';  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET   
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);   
var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OUTPUT_Fiche de compta Prof");   webAppSheet.appendRow([initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme]);    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <center>
      <a href="https://www.breaking-smart.com/">
        <img src="http://www.breaking-smart.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/logobr.png" alt="Breaking Smart®" width="150"; height="60.125">
      </a>
    </center>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-with, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Fiche Compta Prof</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Finger+Paint&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <style>
        h1 {
        font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
      }

        p {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }

        .form-control {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <div class="header">
      <h1 style="text-align:center;background-color:#18408a;color:#ffffff">Fiche compta Prof</h1>
    </div>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function AddRow()
    {
      var initiales = document.getElementById("initiales").value;
      var prenom_eleve = document.getElementById("prenom_eleve").value;
      var date_cours = document.getElementById("date_cours").value;
      var heure_cours = document.getElementById("heure_cours").value;
      var duree_cours = document.getElementById("duree_cours").value;
      var lien_urgence = document.getElementById("lien_urgence").value;
      var chronometre = document.getElementById("chronometre").value;
      var bouton_record = document.getElementById("bouton_record").value;
      var bouton_exit = document.getElementById("bouton_exit").value;
      var probleme = document.getElementById("probleme").value;
      if(initiales != '' && prenom_eleve != '' && date_cours != '' && heure_cours != '' && duree_cours != '' && lien_urgence != '' && chronometre != '' && bouton_record != '' && bouton_exit != '' && probleme != '')
      {
      google.script.run.AddRecord(initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme);
      document.getElementById("initiales").value = '';
      document.getElementById("prenom_eleve").value = '';
      document.getElementById("date_cours").value = '';
      document.getElementById("heure_cours").value = '';
      document.getElementById("duree_cours").value = '';
      document.getElementById("lien_urgence").value = '';
      document.getElementById("chronometre").value = '';
      document.getElementById("bouton_record").value = '';
      document.getElementById("bouton_exit").value = "";
      document.getElementById("probleme").value = "";
      document.getElementById("display_error").innerHTML = "";
      }
      else
      {
      document.getElementById("display_error").innerHTML = "Merci de remplir tous les champs !";
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="font-family: Finger Paint; color: #18408a; text-align: center; class" >
  <div style="padding: 12px;" >
  <form>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="initiales">Initiales Prof</label>
  <input type="text" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="initiales" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="prenom_eleve">Prénom Elève</label>
  <input type="text" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="prenom_eleve" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="date_cours">Date du cours</label>
  <input type="date" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="date_cours" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="heure_cours">Heure de début de cours</label>
  <input type="time" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="heure_cours" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="duree_cours">Durée exacte du cours (en min.)</label>
  <input type="number" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="duree_cours" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="lien_urgence" >Lien d'urgence ? Si oui, pourquoi ?</label>
  <input type="text" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="lien_urgence" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="chronometre" >Chronomètre présent ?</label>
  <input type="text" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="chronometre" class="form-control "/>
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="bouton_record" >Bouton RECORD présent ?</label>
  <input type="text" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="bouton_record" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="bouton_exit" >Bouton EXIT utilisé pour quitter la Smart Room ?</label>
  <input type="text" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="bouton_exit" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="probleme" >Problème technique ou autre(s) remarque(s) ?</label>
  <input type="text" style="display: block; width: 50%; padding: .375rem .75rem; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; color: #495057; background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: .25rem" id="probleme" class="form-control" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <input type="button" style="font-family: Finger Paint;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 700;padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;border: none;border-radius: 20px;widht: auto;background-color:#be0115;color:white" value="Envoyer" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddRow()" />
  <div id="display_error" style="color: red" ></div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, how about using `withSuccessHandler` for `google.script.run`? By this, after `AddRecord` is worked, the function in `withSuccessHandler` is run. I thought that this might be useful. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
google.script.run.AddRecord(initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme);
document.getElementById("initiales").value = '';
document.getElementById("prenom_eleve").value = '';
document.getElementById("date_cours").value = '';
document.getElementById("heure_cours").value = '';
document.getElementById("duree_cours").value = '';
document.getElementById("lien_urgence").value = '';
document.getElementById("chronometre").value = '';
document.getElementById("bouton_record").value = '';
document.getElementById("bouton_exit").value = "";
document.getElementById("probleme").value = "";
document.getElementById("display_error").innerHTML = "";
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {
  document.getElementById("initiales").value = '';
  document.getElementById("prenom_eleve").value = '';
  document.getElementById("date_cours").value = '';
  document.getElementById("heure_cours").value = '';
  document.getElementById("duree_cours").value = '';
  document.getElementById("lien_urgence").value = '';
  document.getElementById("chronometre").value = '';
  document.getElementById("bouton_record").value = '';
  document.getElementById("bouton_exit").value = "";
  document.getElementById("probleme").value = "";
  document.getElementById("display_error").innerHTML = "Succeeded.";
}).AddRecord(initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme);
```

#### Note:

- In this situation, you can also retutn the value of `Succeeded.` from the function `AddRecord`. In that case, the value can be used like `.withSuccessHandler((returnedValue) => {`.

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: I modified the HTML code, but it seems that it doesn't work. Should I also modify the .gs ? Currently it looks like :

Comment: {function AddRecord(initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xPkCBdPAc0OOGTsDxSAz7Rx4kYEfqiEUsUCaYXFV-hc/edit#gid=1182006059';  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OUTPUT_Fiche de compta Prof");
  webAppSheet.appendRow([initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme]);
  
}

Comment: @Rui Fernandes Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In that case, Google Apps Script is not required to be modified. But if you are using the script as Web Apps, when you redeploy the Web Apps as new version and test it again, what result will you obtain? If this was not the direct solution of your current issue, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thank you for your reply. Even after I tried to deploy a new version, it still doesn't work. May I grant you access to the sheet?

Comment: @Rui Fernandes Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. The reason that your issue is not resolved is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. Because when I tested the modified script, no error occurs and "Succeeded." is displayed. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can provide the script, please add it to your question. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: @Rui Fernandes By the way, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `it still doesn't work`?

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help and no worries for your English - mine is neither perfect :) Please find below the used script :

Comment: `function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('BS_webapp_fiche-compta');
}`

Comment: `function AddRecord(initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xPkCBdPAc0OOGTsDxSAz7Rx4kYEfqiEUsUCaYXFV-hc/edit#gid=1182006059';  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OUTPUT_Fiche de compta Prof");
  webAppSheet.appendRow([initiales, prenom_eleve, date_cours, heure_cours, duree_cours, lien_urgence, chronometre, bouton_record, bouton_exit, probleme]);
  
}`

Comment: @Rui Fernandes Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that when the script is put to the comment, the readability becomes low. So when you show the script, can you add it to your question? By this, I would like to confirm your current situation. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228243/discussion-between-rui-fernandes-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Rui Fernandes Thank you for replying and adding your current script. When I saw your updated question, unfortunately, it seems that your script doesn't reflect my answer. I think that this is the reason of your current issue. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize. By the way, can I ask you about the detail of `it still doesn't work` in your 1st replying comment?

Comment: Actually, I have posted this script, but I also change `AddRecord`. But, I also changed to `withSuccessHandler`, and it doesn't display the success message.

Comment: @Rui Fernandes Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your current script from your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you add your current script for replicating your issue? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?